# Does Not Name A Type in C++

Tags: c++, types, header

in C++ when i get an error that says xxxxx does not name a type in yyy.h

What does that mean?

`yyy.h` has included the header that `xxxx` is in.

Example, I use:

```
typedef CP_M_ReferenceCounted FxRC;
```

and I have included `CP_M_ReferenceCounted.h` in `yyy.h`

I am missing some basic understanding, what is it?

Comment: @JT: would you be able to add the exact error message ?

Comment: and how's `CP_M_ReferenceCounted` defined in its `.h`?  "Does not name a type" suggests it does not name a type (maybe some namespace issue...?)

Comment: The full error message at a minimum. Preferably some code that generates the error.

Comment: Martin Martin, +20 we have a beer together!

Answer (score 7):

That seems you need to refer to the namespace accordingly. For example, the following yyy.h and test.cpp have the same problem as yours:

```
//yyy.h
#ifndef YYY_H__
#define YYY_H__

namespace Yyy {

class CP_M_ReferenceCounted
{
};

}

#endif

//test.cpp
#include "yyy.h"

typedef CP_M_ReferenceCounted FxRC;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

        return 0;
}
```

The error would be

```
...error: CP_M_ReferenceCounted does not name a type
```

But add a line "using namespace Yyy;" fixes the problem as below:

```
//test.cpp
#include "yyy.h"
// add this line
using namespace Yyy;

typedef CP_M_ReferenceCounted FxRC;
...
```

So please check the namespace scope in your .h headers.

Comment: I would recommend instead replacing
    CP_M_ReferenceCounted
with
    Yyy::CP_M_ReferenceCounted.
The "using" keyword is applied globally to the file and is therefore generalizing what actually needs it. Prepending CP_M_ReferenceCounted with Yyy:: improves readability and suggests to other developers that you are aware CP_M_ReferenceCounted has been defined in that namespace (the namespace of Yyy), and might also help them understand the scope of such a typedef in that any other source code that uses it (especially outside of this source file) might also need to prepend this namespace.

Answer (score 3):

The inclusion of the CP_M_ReferenceCounted type is probably lexically AFTER the typedef... can you link to the two files directly, or reproduce the problem in a simple sample?

Answer (score 3):

Although possibly unrelated to OP's original question... this is an error I just had and shows how this error could occur.

When you define a type in a C++ class and you return it, you need to specify the class in which the type belongs.

For example:

```
class ClassName{
public:
 typedef vector<int> TypeName;
 TypeName GetData();
};
```

Then GetData() must be defined as:

```
ClassName::TypeName ClassName::GetData(){...}
```

not

```
TypeName ClassName::GetData(){...}
```

Otherwise the compiler will come back with the error:

```
error: 'TypeName' does not name a type
```

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, you should try to check the `namespace` first.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you didn't copy paste this yyy.h file from some other class header and keep the same "YYY_H__" in the new #ifndef as in the original file.  I just did this and realized my mistake.  Make sure to update your new YYY_H__ to represent the new class. Otherwise, obviously, YYY_H__ will already be defined from the original file and the important stuff in this header will be skipped.

Comment: If this was indeed your problem, make sure you `<make> clean` before you try compiling again, so that the old define macro is cleared out.