# C++ problems on Types ( Type Names )

Tags: c++, class, templates

sample code:

file: LinkedStack.h

```
#include "NodeType.h"

#ifndef LINKEDSTACK_H
#define LINKEDSTACK_H

template <class ItemType>
class LinkedStack {
public:
    NodeType topPtr;
};
```

file: NodeType.h

```
#ifndef NODETYPE_H
#define NODETYPE_H

template <class ItemType>
class NodeType {
public:

    ItemType info;
    NodeType *nextElement;

};

#endif  /* NODETYPE_H */
```

file: main.cpp

```
#include "NodeType.h"
#include "LinkedStack.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, I keep getting:

**LinkedStack.h:20: error: `NodeType' does not name a type**

However NodeType is already defined and included?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761018/does-not-name-a-type-in-c

Downvoting as poor research effort - at least google the error before posting a question.

Comment: @djechlin Please see response of hmjd and the link you provided, if you still think they are duplicates, fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NodeType` is a `template`. Change to:

```
NodeType<ItemType> topPtr;
```